# Как получить список параметров функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например есть функция:

```
def some(data, ln, o):
    pass
```

Как получить список аргументов функции например в таком виде? :

```
["data", "ln", 'o']
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218616/how-to-get-method-parameter-names

Comment: @entithat, спасибо!